# Is there a way to map an empty String to null using MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org) for mapping a DTO to an entity and vice versa in my Spring Boot application.

Is there a way to map empty strings to null using [`@Mapping`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapping.html)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply use the [`expression`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) within the `@Mapping`

```
@Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java(source.name.isEmpty() ? null : source.name)")
Dog convert(Cat source);
```

Comment: If the field has a private access, we may use the getter method in place of the field name. Eg:
@Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java(source.getName.isEmpty() ? null : source.getName)")
Dog convert(Cat source);

Comment: What a boilerplate!

Answer (score 20):

Using an expression, as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61286743/1108305), is possible.  I personally prefer to do this a bit safer, and perhaps a bit more declarative.

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping( target = "s2",  qualifiedBy = EmptyStringToNull.class )
    Target map( Source source);

    @EmptyStringToNull
    default String emptyStringToNull(String s) {
        return s.isEmpty() ? null : s;
    }

    @Qualifier
    @java.lang.annotation.Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
    public @interface EmptyStringToNull {
    }

    class Source {

        private String s1;
        private String s2;

        public String getS1() {
            return s1;
        }

        public void setS1(String s1) {
            this.s1 = s1;
        }

        public String getS2() {
            return s2;
        }

        public void setS2(String s2) {
            this.s2 = s2;
        }
    }

    class Target {

        private String s1;
        private String s2;

        public String getS1() {
            return s1;
        }

        public void setS1(String s1) {
            this.s1 = s1;
        }

        public String getS2() {
            return s2;
        }

        public void setS2(String s2) {
            this.s2 = s2;
        }
    }
}
```

You can re-use the `EmptyStringToNull` qualifier as many times as you'd like and your not dependent on the parameter name.

Comment: Is there any way to do that for all strings in all mappers?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like it to work globally in the mapper class and intercept any String-Mappings you can simply implement the following:

```java
default String mapEmptyString(String string) {
 string != null && !string.isEmpty() ? string : null;
}
```

This will map any `null` or empty `String` source to `null`.

Comment: Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Condition like the [documentation suggests](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#conditional-mapping).

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

     Target map( Source source);

     @Condition
     default boolean isNotEmpty(String value) {
        return value != null && !value.isEmpty();
     }
}
```